# Learn iOS development (Already know Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to start programming for iOS. I already have a solid footing in Objective-C, so I am not looking for a guide on Objective-C. I am NOT a beginner.

Could any of you please point me in the right direction for tutorials on developing iOS apps, NOT for learning Objective-C?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check out the documentation on [http://developer.apple.com/](http://developer.apple.com/)
They have everything from class references, to sample code, to video tutorials.

Comment: This is one of the most comprehensive sites for iOS tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not these sorts of generic, subjective advice questions.

Comment: There are a ton of questions just like this one. Please search first, then ask.

Comment: [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple.

Comment: Did you even search before asking question.

Comment: I apologize for not being as thorough with my searching as I should have.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to follow written tutorials these are some I found helpful but I recommend you to go through [**iOS developer Library**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) and [**Apple sample codes**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) first. If you start following tutorials you will simply copy paste code snippets:

1) http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/iphone/

2) http://www.raywenderlich.com/

3) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_iPhone_iPad_eBooks (One of the best reource)

4) http://www.cimgf.com/about/

5) http://appsamuck.com/

**And most important**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

**Before you get started here are few links from Apple which will help a lot and one must go through it once.**

1) [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072)

2) [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) *Recently Posted by Apple*

3)  [Your Second iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318) *Tutorial with Storyboards*

4) [Your First App Store Submission](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375)  *Guidelines about creating certificates and submitting Apps to App store*

5) [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

For specific example guides on making iPhone apps, have a look through the [iOS tutorials on Mobiletuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/iphone/). Their tutorials are usually well written, and easy to follow.

Ray Wenderlich's [early tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) (> 1-2 year ago) are also another good place to start. Recently he's been tackling much more advanced tutorials.

[TreeHouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ios-4-foundations/?cid=193) is also a good place to learn. They have some free tutorials, but otherwise there's a membership required. It's from the ThinkVitamin guys and their tutorials are A++ for clarity, detail, and quality.

I wrote a [blog post on the subject](http://randomtype.ca/blog/so-you-want-to-develop-for-the-iphone/) about a year ago. Most of the resources are still relevant. I'd recommend reading through the following at least before releasing an app:

- [iOS App Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072) - Good primer on the subject and worth reading because Apple published it.
- [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) - This is a must. It will keep you from making mistakes that get your app rejected from the app store.
- [Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) - ARC takes care of most of this, but it's worth having a cursory knowledge of it.

If you're doing non-game apps, read up on [View Controller Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and when I learned to program iPhone I referred to apple's [Core Data Recipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) frequently.

[AppsAmuck has 31 example applications](http://appsamuck.com/) you can look at as well, albeit they have some bad habits/programming practices so take their tutorials with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Go up to iTunes U and look for the stanford lecture series.  They go through about 20 lectures on iPhone/iPad development.  One of the early classes focuses on Obj-C, but it still has a glean towards using Obj-C for iPad/iPhone development, so it might be worth a watch.